# printing an int value right after a String value

Tags: java, string, integer, int

I have the following example code:

```
int pay = 80;
int bonus = 65;
System.out.println(pay + bonus + " " + bonus + pay);
```

could someone please explain to me why I get the following output:

```
145 6580
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is interpreting the expression from left to right.

1. `pay + bonus` is interpreted as a mathematical function, so it adds the values to make 145. The `+` here is a plus operator.
2. The moment you concatenate the `" "`, Java converts the expression into a String. The `+` here is a concatenate operator.
3. Performing `+ pay` converts `pay` to a String and concatenates it, because the expression is a String.
4. Also doing `+ bonus` converts `bonus` to a String and concatenates it, also because of the previous expression.

Comment: @user2959072, I'm glad you got the information you needed. I highly encourage selecting an answer when you can. :D

Comment: I would if I knew how to. Still new to all of this.

Comment: @user2959072, there should be a checkmark icon next to each answer, that lets you select an answer. If not, then whatever! Haha.

Answer (score 3):

Because, this is `operator overloading` issue. Here, First `+` is `plus` operator and last `+` is `concat` operator.

```
 System.out.println(pay + bonus + " " + bonus + pay);
                        |                     |
                      (plus)                (concat)
```

Answer (score 1):

First it adds the two variables and at last it concatinates as string because the integers are converted into strings

For concatenation, imagine a and b are integers:

```
"" + a + b
```

This works because the + operator is overloaded if either operand is a String. It then converts the other operand to a string (if needed) and results in a new concatenated string. You could also invoke `Integer.toString(a) + Integer.toString(b)` for concatenation

Answer (score 0):

`bonus` and `pay` are both ints, and therefore going to be combined into a single int result.

You need to insert an empty string between them.

Answer (score 0):

first is `plus operator`  and last is `concat operator`

Answer (score 0):

As the others are saying the compiler is first adding the integer values and then printing the result, after " " the total value is changed to  `String` type and after that `+` operator is functioning as a concat action. To not get that output, you can do this:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(pay) + String.valueOf(bonus) + " " + String.valueOf(bonus) + String.valueOf(pay));
```

Comment: You type `String.valueOf(var)`? I always do `""+var`; it is much faster. For the specific example, I usually do `System.out.println(pay + "" + bonus + " " + bonus + "" + pay);`

Comment: @Quincunx: What your doing will make the compiler to instantiate a new String object with the value of "" so it'll be much slower than `valueOf`.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st pay and bonus in the println returns an integer. So it computes pay+bonus and returns it as an integer before printing it out.

However, after the "". The + operation then becomes a concatenation of strings and everything after that is returned as a concatenated string. Hence, ("" + bonus + pay) would be returned as "6580".

Answer (score 0):

before " ",pay and bonus as integer, added result is 145.
after " ",bonus and pay as String,result is "6580"

Answer (score 0):

what is surrounded by " " is referred to as a 'literal print' and gets printed exactly. The "+" sign is the concatenator operator and concatenates the string with the value that is stored in the variables. pay and bonus are declared as int, but is automatically converted to a String for the purpose of printing out.

You can print an arithmetic expression within a System.out.print statement. Use parentheses around the arithmetic expression to avoid unexpected problems.

```
        System.out.println("ex" + 3 + 4);   // becomes answer 34
        System.out.println("ex" + (3 + 4));   // becomes answer 7
```