# Java: Adding int to string to int - strange behaviour

Tags: java

I noticed something like this:

```
String s = 1 + 2 + " whatsgoingon " + 3 + 4 + 5;
System.out.println(s);
```

Returns:
`3 whatsgoingon 345`

Can someone explain this behaviour? Why are the first two numbers added together and then converted to a string, but the last three numbers are converted to strings and then concatenated.

Comment: @devnull i don't thi nk this question is duplicate of the one you have flagged.

Comment: The Java Specification Language explains it in details: [§15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804805/printing-an-int-value-right-after-a-string-value/

Comment: @maxx777 Not sure what makes you think so.  Added another one.  That said this has been asked and answered scores of times.

Comment: @devnull i agree for this one and now this question should be closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in the expression:

```
1 + 2 + " whatsgoingon " + 3 + 4 + 5
```

is evaluated from left to right as

```
(((((1 + 2) + " whatsgoingon ") + 3) + 4) + 5)
```

so the first '+' operator is seen as an arithmetic operator, since at that moment there is no strings yet involved, after concatenating a string, then the '+' operators are seen as string concatenation operations so the numbers are typecasted to Strings.

If you want to add arithmetically also the last three integers, put them between parentheses:

```
1 + 2 + " whatsgoingon " + (3 + 4 + 5)
```